# In Excel 2007, what does the Header Row check box do to the worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

When do I use the header row check box in Excel when working with tables?

Answer (score 1):

[source](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/turn-excel-table-headers-on-or-off-HA010062136.aspx)

It defines whether you want the top row to be data or headers